# Add text to files with Python/Regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm using Python/Regex with Jupyter notebook. The purpose of the script is to change into multiple .adoc files:

When finding in the text of the file ".png" change to "image:.png", for example:

- picture.png change to image:picture.png
- figure.png change to image:figure.png

The code I'm using is this one in Python, but the way I'm doing it, it takes the first occurrence of the filename and replicates it to the other filenames in the text.

```
import os, re

path = "C:\\Projetos\\venvs\\converte"
caminho=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path),"converte_pages\data") 
directory = os.listdir(caminho)
os.chdir(caminho)
for file in directory:
    open_file = open(file,'r')
    read_file = open_file.read() 
    regex = re.compile('(?![^a-z]).*png')
    reg = regex.finditer(read_file)
    for r in reg:
        read_file = re.sub(r'(?![^a-z]).*png', 'image:'+r.group(), read_file)             
print(read_file)
```

At the moment I'm just reading the file, I haven't done the recording yet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little hard to tell from your description, but assuming you want to replace instances of `xxx.png` with `image:xxx.png` in your text you are on the right track using `re.sub`.  The key to success in that case is using a **backreference** (e.g., `\g<0>`) to refer back the text found by your regular expression.  See [the Python re library docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for additional information.

Here is a simplified example to illustrate the technique:

```
import re

read_str = "I used picture.png and figure.png to create the collage."

pattern = re.compile(r"\w+\.png")

pattern.sub(r"image:\g<0>", read_str)
```

```
'I used image:picture.png and image:figure.png to create the collage.'
```